# GMail: Count searched hits

Tags: search, scripting, gmail-api

I have a problem with the [GmailApp search(query) function](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/gmail/gmail-app#search(String)).

According to the manual it uses [Gmail queries](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190?hl=en), so all the arguments should be accessible and return correct results.

```js
var bigThreads = GmailApp.search('in:chats newer_than:1d');
Logger.log(bigThreads.length);
```

When I take the filter on the eMail-search-field I get 6 line back. In the log I see the count 2.

Does anyone have a idea - where my fault is?

Comment: To clarify, you are entering the exact same query string `in:chats newer_than:1d` into both the search bar in the Gmail interface, and via the GmailApp.search API?

Comment: I think I found the point: When you filter about the commandline you get all steps separat back. When you count the steps you get only the "Chat with" back.